# Is a TXB0108 apt for level-shifting in SPI programming?

Tags: cmos, level-shifting, programmer

I plan to use a TXB0108 to level-shift between the cheap CH341A programmer voltage and the Winbond W25Q64FW from 3.3V to 1.8V

On the silicon I can read:

`25Q64FWS1G
1429`

Comment: You should read [this](https://e2e.ti.com/support/interface/voltage_level/f/391/t/610953?TXB0108-SD-card-SPI-working-intermittently-MISO-line).

Comment: I try to avoid using bidirectional auto sensing level shifters when I can. There are many issues with these level shifters, especially when driven by high-ish impedances

Comment: SPI uses only unidirectional signals, so you should use unidirectional or direction-controlled level shifters. Anyway, you have not told use which of the W25Q64FW variants you are using, or how many signals in each direction you have.

Comment: @CL. I plan to read and write through a programmer. What do you mean variants? The text on the silicon reads as I reported in the question description

Comment: @LongPham I use it with a cheap board; can't say that the same issue will happen with different voltages though

Comment: Do you need highspeed ? If not,2 pairs of R-R divider will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The TXB0108 requires the other devices to have a drive strength of a least 2 mA, but the W25Q64FW is specified for only 0.1 mA. And other auto-sensing level shifters have similar restrictions, so it is not possible to use the Dual/Quad SPI modes.

In normal SPI mode, you have three unidirectional signals to the flash, and one coming from it. This can be handled with a four-bit level shifter with individual direction controls, e.g., (SN)74AVC4T774; there's also the 74AVC4T3144 for this 3+1 combination.